# How to parse this data type in R?

Tags: r, json, parsing, tableau-api, associative-array

I am trying to parse this data type in R in order to get a visualisation in Tableau (tried with Tableau but it is quite complicated and doesn't give a good result).

Below is an example of the data type I am trying to parse:

```
{"010010208022":215,"010010205002":195,"010010208012":184,"010010208021":165,"010010206001":132,"010010205003":110,"010010211001":100,"010010208024":93,"010010201002":91,"010010205001":84,"010010210002":82,"010510310002":75,"010010203001":74}
```

Basically this is just one entry. I have three columns of this type. I am trying to parse each entry and sum up the numbers (after each colon) to get a new column for each of the three variables which holds the sums of the numbers for each entry.

This is for using it in Tableau to get a visualization using these totals.

The data I have is an excel sheet which includes three variables stored as Text in Excel which have the above data type.

The imported dataset in R looks as follows:

```
> dput(head(dataset))
structure(list(census_block_group = c(10010201001, 10010201002, 
10010202001, 10010202002, 10010203001, 10010203002), date_range_start = c(1538352000, 
1538352000, 1538352000, 1538352000, 1538352000, 1538352000), 
    date_range_end = c(1541030400, 1541030400, 1541030400, 1541030400, 
    1541030400, 1541030400), raw_visit_count = c(54544, 19583, 
    24552, 61089, 41139, 91053), raw_visitor_count = c(14460, 
    2351, 3020, 7123, 5132, 20907), visitor_home_cbgs = c("{\"010010208022\":215,\"010010205002\":195,\"010010208012\":184,\"010010208021\":165,\"010010206001\":132,\"010010205003\":110,\"010010211001\":100,\"010010208024\":93,\"010010201002\":91,\"010010205001\":84,\"010010210002\":82,\"010510310002\":75,\"010010203001\":74,\"010010208011\":73,\"010010204002\":62,\"010510309011\":61,\"010510309012\":61,\"010010207001\":58,\"010010209004\":58,\"010010207002\":55,\"010010209002\":54,\"010010208023\":53,\"011250112001\":53}", 
    "{\"010010208022\":143,\"010010208021\":140,\"010010205002\":116,\"010010206001\":87,\"010010208012\":83,\"010010205003\":56}", 
    "{\"010010208022\":193,\"010010205002\":170,\"010010208012\":112,\"010010206001\":96,\"010010203001\":84,\"010010205003\":82,\"010010208021\":74,\"010010208024\":71,\"010010205001\":67,\"010010201002\":65,\"010010204002\":55,\"010010208011\":55}", 
    "{\"010010205002\":326,\"010010208022\":287,\"010010208012\":184,\"010010206001\":170,\"010010208021\":162,\"010010208024\":145,\"010010205003\":141,\"010010205001\":125,\"010010203001\":121,\"010510310002\":113,\"010010204002\":99,\"010010211001\":96,\"010010207001\":95,\"010010201002\":94,\"010510309011\":94,\"010010208011\":88,\"010010209004\":79,\"010510309012\":78,\"010510310001\":72,\"010010207002\":70,\"010010210002\":69,\"010010208023\":67,\"010510301001\":58,\"010510313001\":57,\"010010202001\":56,\"010010209002\":56,\"010510311002\":52}", 
    "{\"010010208022\":247,\"010010205002\":235,\"010010208024\":135,\"010010208012\":121,\"010010205003\":116,\"010010206001\":111,\"010010208021\":99,\"010010209004\":91,\"010010204002\":86,\"010010205001\":83,\"010010201002\":62,\"010010207002\":61,\"010510310002\":60,\"010010209002\":58,\"010010207001\":56,\"010010208023\":56,\"010010208011\":55,\"010510309011\":54,\"010010204001\":52}", 
    "{\"010010205002\":391,\"010010208022\":328,\"010010208012\":181,\"010010208024\":174,\"010010206001\":169,\"010010205003\":161,\"010510310002\":160,\"010010208021\":158,\"010010203001\":152,\"010010205001\":138,\"010010204002\":130,\"010510309011\":129,\"010510309012\":128,\"010010207001\":113,\"010510310001\":105,\"010010209004\":99,\"010010201002\":96,\"010010211001\":93,\"010510313001\":89,\"010010207002\":85,\"010010208011\":85,\"010510301001\":81,\"010510311002\":78,\"010010209002\":76,\"010010210002\":71,\"010010208023\":70,\"010010202002\":63,\"010510307012\":60,\"010010204001\":59,\"010010209001\":56,\"010010202001\":54,\"010010204003\":54,\"010510301004\":53,\"010010206002\":53,\"010510309023\":51,\"010510301003\":50}"
    ), visitor_work_cbgs = c("{\"010010208022\":233,\"011250112001\":106,\"011010001001\":70,\"011010002001\":70,\"010510313001\":63,\"010010209004\":59,\"010010205002\":54}", 
    "{\"010010208022\":223}", "{\"010010208022\":258}", "{\"010010208022\":262,\"011010002001\":90,\"010510313001\":87,\"011010001001\":86,\"010010209004\":72,\"010010205002\":68,\"010510311001\":57,\"010010202001\":50}", 
    "{\"010010208022\":265,\"010010209004\":66,\"010510313001\":59,\"011010001001\":57,\"011010002001\":55,\"010010202001\":54}", 
    "{\"010010208022\":278,\"011010002001\":110,\"011010001001\":106,\"010510313001\":104,\"010510311001\":82,\"010010209004\":80,\"010010205002\":78,\"011010009002\":61,\"011010054072\":59,\"010010202001\":54,\"011010053021\":53,\"010010207002\":50}"
    ), distance_from_home = c(45094, 7346, 6977, 13528, 11597, 
    16162), related_same_day_brand = c("[\"Winn Dixie\",\"Chick-fil-A\",\"walmart\"]", 
    "[\"Winn Dixie\",\"walmart\",\"Chick-fil-A\"]", "[\"America's Thrift Store\",\"Winn Dixie\",\"Chick-fil-A\"]", 
    "[\"Winn Dixie\",\"walmart\",\"America's Thrift Store\",\"Chick-fil-A\",\"Dollar General\"]", 
    "[\"America's Thrift Store\",\"walmart\",\"Chick-fil-A\"]", 
    "[\"Winn Dixie\",\"walmart\",\"America's Thrift Store\"]"
    ), related_same_month_brand = c("[\"walmart\",\"Dollar General\",\"Chick-fil-A\",\"America's Thrift Store\",\"mcdonalds\",\"Zaxby's\",\"Jack's Family Restaurants\",\"Winn Dixie\",\"Waffle House\",\"Chevron\"]", 
    "[\"walmart\",\"America's Thrift Store\",\"Chick-fil-A\",\"Dollar General\",\"mcdonalds\",\"Winn Dixie\",\"Zaxby's\",\"Wendy's\",\"Sonic\",\"Taco Bell\"]", 
    "[\"walmart\",\"America's Thrift Store\",\"Dollar General\",\"Chick-fil-A\",\"mcdonalds\",\"Winn Dixie\",\"Zaxby's\",\"Sonic\",\"Wendy's\",\"Taco Bell\"]", 
    "[\"walmart\",\"Dollar General\",\"Chick-fil-A\",\"mcdonalds\",\"America's Thrift Store\",\"Winn Dixie\",\"Zaxby's\",\"Sonic\",\"Wendy's\",\"Publix Super Markets\"]", 
    "[\"walmart\",\"Dollar General\",\"mcdonalds\",\"America's Thrift Store\",\"Chick-fil-A\",\"Winn Dixie\",\"Zaxby's\",\"Wendy's\",\"Taco Bell\",\"Sonic\"]", 
    "[\"America's Thrift Store\",\"Dollar General\",\"walmart\",\"Winn Dixie\",\"Chick-fil-A\",\"Zaxby's\",\"Waffle House\",\"Jack's Family Restaurants\",\"Publix Super Markets\",\"Sonic\"]"
    ), top_brands = c("[]", "[]", "[]", "[\"Alabama DMV\",\"Fox's Pizza Den\",\"America's Thrift Store\",\"CrossFit\",\"Habitat for Humanity\"]", 
    "[]", "[\"Winn Dixie\",\"Planet Fitness\",\"America's Thrift Store\",\"Dollar General\",\"fred's\",\"Church's Chicken\",\"Advance Auto Parts\",\"Sunoco\",\"Boost Mobile\",\"Factory Connection\"]"
    ), popularity_by_hour = c("[1840,1666,1562,1541,1735,1977,3045,6630,3445,3681,3529,3894,4224,4292,4531,6463,5084,5378,4814,4162,3394,2918,2615,2074]", 
    "[2201,2137,2121,2108,2118,2175,2465,4458,1723,1664,1483,1471,1585,1586,1740,3185,2166,2566,2441,2339,2359,2319,2300,2255]", 
    "[1280,1233,1220,1199,1206,1288,1887,6141,2267,2196,2028,2059,2239,2337,2793,4935,2234,2685,2327,2052,1829,1616,1433,1340]", 
    "[1518,1326,1272,1199,1285,1539,2641,7010,4374,4681,4997,5268,5662,5346,5733,7468,6253,6882,5971,4754,3619,2757,2292,1799]", 
    "[3318,3261,3232,3212,3213,3309,4079,7363,3271,3115,3113,3187,3305,3445,3601,7069,4687,5433,5104,4775,4394,3905,3744,3429]", 
    "[2109,1738,1979,2393,2579,2953,4381,8526,5665,5653,5859,6539,7119,7046,6950,9672,8220,9003,7618,6015,4763,3713,3230,2629]"
    ), popularity_by_day = c("{\"Monday\":7542,\"Tuesday\":8610,\"Wednesday\":9274,\"Thursday\":7473,\"Friday\":8060,\"Saturday\":7222,\"Sunday\":6363}", 
    "{\"Monday\":3160,\"Tuesday\":3167,\"Wednesday\":3353,\"Thursday\":2721,\"Friday\":2807,\"Saturday\":2315,\"Sunday\":2060}", 
    "{\"Monday\":3688,\"Tuesday\":4192,\"Wednesday\":4221,\"Thursday\":3876,\"Friday\":3887,\"Saturday\":2846,\"Sunday\":1842}", 
    "{\"Monday\":9091,\"Tuesday\":9653,\"Wednesday\":10016,\"Thursday\":8397,\"Friday\":9017,\"Saturday\":7919,\"Sunday\":6996}", 
    "{\"Monday\":6126,\"Tuesday\":6681,\"Wednesday\":6811,\"Thursday\":5935,\"Friday\":6251,\"Saturday\":5275,\"Sunday\":4060}", 
    "{\"Monday\":13680,\"Tuesday\":13569,\"Wednesday\":14006,\"Thursday\":11815,\"Friday\":13480,\"Saturday\":13697,\"Sunday\":10806}"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Upon importing the excel into R, the variables were stored as character.

I then ran the toJSON command to turn them into JSON type. Upon running typeof command after the toJSON command the result is **character** again.

The error I get now is related to the sum command run on the list (res). The error I get is:

```
Error in sum(unlist(res_home_visitor)) : 
  invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

and the result of unlist command is:

```
visitor_home_cbgs1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "{\"010010208022\":215,\"010010205002\":195,\"010010208012\":184,\"010010208021\":165,\"010010206001\":132,\"010010205003\":110,\"010010211001\":100,\"010010208024\":93"   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                visitor_home_cbgs2    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "{\"010010208022\":143,\"010010208021\":140,\"010010205002\":116,\"010010206001\":87,\"010010208012\":83,\"010010205003\":56}"
```

Now I am new to coding and I have looked up the above data type but I'm not sure if it's called an associative array or JSON (thus the tags in the question).

What I researched and tried is using the split function in Tableau. However, it creates problems as the entries are not of the same size and a lot of the entries are large so the split function will create a lot of columns and this causes a lag and a lot of trouble in Tableau (due to limitation on the number of columns and so..)

** Here's an example of what I am trying to get:

```
{"010479561003":52,"010479561002":52, "110478541030":33}
```

For the above entry the total should be: 52+52+33= **137**

This total (137) would be put into a new column called "totals" which is needed for the visualization.

Comment: "Upon importing the excel into R" - how are you doing this, and what is the object in your R session, is it a `data.frame` with list columns? If we have an example of this object it will be a lot easier to help.

Comment: I basically used the "Import Dataset" in R which essentially runs the following command:  `library(readxl)
dataset <- read_excel("D:/path/dataset.xlsx", 
    sheet = "cbg")`.  Upon running `typeof(dataset)` command the result is `list`

Comment: ok good, next what would be helpful is if you added the output of `dput(head(dataset))` to your question. This will give code I can use to copy & paste into my own R session. Then I can work with the exact same data as you.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: the `dput` you have include gives an error when I copy & paste it; have you omitted any brackets?

Comment: Not brackets but I just removed the extra columns just to save on space. However, I have now edited the question with the exact result of the `dput`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `data.frame` where some columns are JSON. It's my understanding you want to treat each row independently. Therefore, you can `sum` the result of `fromJSON` on a row-by-row basis.

In this example I'm using `library(dplyr)` to

1. `rowwise()` - apply the code to each row
2. `mutate()` - create a new column, which is the result of `sum( unlist( fromJSON() ) )`

```
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)

res <- dataset %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(visitor_home_cbgs_sum = sum( unlist (jsonlite::fromJSON( visitor_home_cbgs ) ) ) ) %>%
  mutate(visitor_work_cbgs_sum = sum( unlist (jsonlite::fromJSON( visitor_work_cbgs ) ) ) )
```

Now we can look at the result by selecting only the original JSON columns, and our newly crated `sum` columns

```
res %>%
  select(visitor_home_cbgs, visitor_home_cbgs_sum, visitor_work_cbgs, visitor_work_cbgs_sum)

# Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
# Groups: <by row>
#   
#   # A tibble: 6 x 4
#   visitor_home_cbgs                     visitor_home_cbg… visitor_work_cbgs                    visitor_work_cbg…
# <chr>                                             <int> <chr>                                            <int>
# 1 "{\"010010208022\":215,\"01001020500…              2188 "{\"010010208022\":233,\"0112501120…               655
# 2 "{\"010010208022\":143,\"01001020802…               625 "{\"010010208022\":223}"                           223
# 3 "{\"010010208022\":193,\"01001020500…              1124 "{\"010010208022\":258}"                           258
# 4 "{\"010010205002\":326,\"01001020802…              3054 "{\"010010208022\":262,\"0110100020…               772
# 5 "{\"010010208022\":247,\"01001020500…              1838 "{\"010010208022\":265,\"0100102090…               556
# 6 "{\"010010205002\":391,\"01001020802…              4093 "{\"010010208022\":278,\"0110100020…              1115
```

---

In this example you only have two columns you want to update, so I'm leaving the two `mutate()` statements in there to be explicit about how this works.

If you have many / an unknown number of columns with JSON values you may want to consider another approach.

Comment: Thanks so much for the swift reply. I will try this now and let you know if it worked.

Comment: The columns are saved as Text in the excel. however, when after importing the excel into R and upon checking the type of the column R is giving result as List type. And the command fromJSON doesn't accept that of course. Do you think trying the toJSON command on the list type to convert it to JSON is worth a try?

Comment: @R.A I've updated my answer with your new `dataset` object

Comment: Thank you so much for your help here. I hope this works. I actually have 3 columns with the same data type as the above. However, if this will work for the two columns available there that should be perfect.

Comment: yeah just use the same code for the 3rd column and you'll be set